# edit article from front page for registered user

Tags: joomla1.5, article

I am trying to implement for a registered user to edit an article from front-end section of joomla 1.5. Is it possible? if so how can I proceed. I am new in joomla. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you have to do. First you have to make sure that you have the correct user permissions set up. Go to your /administrator page and go to the user menu. There are a list of permissions in there - should be self explanatory.

The second thing you need to do is enable editing articles. Again, go to your administrator page and click the content menu. On the tool bar there is an 'options' button. Click that and there is an 'edit'tab. Enable all the options.

Now when the user logs into the front end, there will be a small 'edit article' icon on the article, but only if they have permission to edit it. If you find this icon isn't there, double check the user permissions.

Comment: I have done as you described in first option but I didnt find out the second option. Can you please help me for that. My current version is Version 1.5.26

Comment: Ah yes, sorry for 1.5 the second lot of options aren't there. Article editing is enabled by default. If you cant see the edit icon, go to content menu and select parameters from toolbar. Enable everything. If you still cant see it, check you are logged to the frontend as the super user. If still cant see it, check permissions. If still no joy, it could be your template - use the basic joomla template to debug.